# Is it possible to re-use Specifications in another entity in Spring Data Jpa?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

Given these entities :

```
public class Parent {
    private List<Child> children;

    // others fields
}

public class Child {
    private Parent parent;

    // others fields
}
```

I want to apply a specification that exists for `Parent`, but with the `Child` as root :

```
public class ParentSpecs {
    public static Specification<Parent> withComplexFilter(String filter) {
        return (parent, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            Predicate predicate;
            // complex algorithm that works, but that I don't want to duplicate
            return predicate;
        };
    }
}

public class ChildSpecs {
    public static Specification<Child> withComplexFilterOnParentField(String filter) {
        return (child, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            Path<Object> parent = child.get("parent");
            Root<Parent> root = null; // how to build a root from the "Child" root ?
            return ParentSpecs.withComplexFilter(filter).toPredicate(root, query, criteriaBuilder);
        };
    }
}
```

Does turning the specification into a predicate to use it in `ChildSpecs` seems to be a good solution ?

How can we use a `Root<Parent>` when we are supposed to use a `Root<Child>`?

Answer (score 0):

The `Root` type basically refers to the FROM part of the SQL query. To get another root, you want a subquery:

```
return (child, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
  final Subquery<ReturnType> subquery = query.subquery(ReturnType.class);
  final Root<Parent> subroot = subquery.from(Parent.class);
  subquery.select("parentField");
  // call shared code
  return criteriaBuilder.equal(subquery, child.get("something"));
}
```

This is essentially like the following SQL:

```
SELECT ... FROM child c WHERE c.something = (
  SELECT parentField FROM parent WHERE (...shared conditions...)
);
```

Comment: I'd prefer to have my predicate with a join and where clauses instead of a subquery, but that's a potential good lead. Unfortunatly, using a query.from(Parent.class) create a cross join